# Best way to check an element's width?

Tags: javascript, css

Will checking the `width` attribute be sufficient to make sure my DOM element has a striclty positive width or should I also check for css rules (I am only looking for elements that have a fixed number of pixels as a CSS rule, no % width).

```
if (element.offsetWidth && element.offsetWidth > 0) // do stuff
```

OR

```
if ((element.offsetWidth && element.offsetWidth > 0)
     || (element.style && element.style.width
         && int(element.style.width.replace("px", ""), 10)>0 ) // do stuff
```

I would rather go for the first one but I want to make sure that setting the CSS rule will also set the `width` attribute.

---- EDIT ----

Actually `offsetWidth` seems to be better than `width` in any case. I changed `width` to `offsetWidth`.

Does it make the second option (checking for the CSS) worthless?

Comment: How can you have a negative width?

Comment: I want to avoid zero width element.

Comment: Ah. I would regard zero as "positive" in that it is non-negative. Clearer, purhaps, to say `Making sure the DOM element has width greater than zero`?

Comment: You're right, edits have been made. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`element.offsetWidth` should suffice - and no, checking the `style` element will not be necessary

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you check the computed style of the element

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).width
```

you can rest assured that the value returned is correct and way more accurate than the applied css rule (say you have in an external css file width: 0!important;, it'll override the inline one and won't be reported to you by el.style.width

Comment: depends on what browsers that need to be supported: http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Unfortunately support for this feature is still a bit too scarce so I can use it safely.

Comment: For old IE's (are they even browsers?) you can use element.currentStyle -- notice, it sometimes (though not common) fails.